# How is "top 99,99% this year" calculated?

Tags: support

Just curious to the method, used to calculate the figure below (well, the `top 0.16%`; the reputation I kind of understand):

[image]

If I look at the pages (36 users per page), I count 7625 and something pages. That makes 274508 users. When the year rank is 11, my calculation is 11÷274508 = 0,000040072.

In other words, that would make:

```
top 0,0040072%.
```

#### My questions are:

- How often is this figure updated (since I hardly see them change *ever*)
- How is this figure calculated.

Curious to the calculation method ever since I earned rep 1.

Comment: ... ["users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues"](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/year/askubuntu) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you skim to the [last page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/year/askubuntu/2015-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=232) you'll notice that actually only 6931 users are ranked;

Doing the math:

```
x / 100 = 11 / 6931
x = 11 / 6931 * 100 = 0,158707257 =~ 0,16%
```

---

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86400/302251), User Reputation Leagues are recalculated daily.

Probably you don't see a difference because the wider the timeframe addressed by a league the more the reputation in function of the rank has an exponential-like trend (i.e. the more you approach the top user the bigger is the reputation gap between contiguous users); this means that variations in the first page e.g. in the quarterly / yearly / all time leagues are less likely to happen, since they require bigger reputation changes.

You can probably appreciate the difference much more e.g. in the weekly league.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!